# Cannot install npm @angular/cli on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When I try `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get an error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_name/.npm/_logs/2017-07-15T16_09_19_320Z-debug.log
```

Therofore I run `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` but I get an error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: acorn@4.0.13 (node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-4.0.13.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @types/serve-static@1.7.31 (node_modules/@types/serve-static):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/serve-static/-/serve-static-1.7.31.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: acorn@5.1.1 (node_modules/acorn):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.1.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @types/minimatch@2.0.29 (node_modules/@types/minimatch):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/minimatch/-/minimatch-2.0.29.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: uuid@3.1.0 (node_modules/uuid):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime '/home/my_name/dev/angular/angular-cli/node_modules/.staging/uuid-d533788a/lib/bytesToUuid.js'

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/source-map/-/source-map-0.5.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_name/.npm/_logs/2017-07-15T16_09_46_119Z-debug.log
```

Why I cannot do it. Recently nothing works.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: use `sudo npm install`

Comment: Don't use sudo npm install, fix your permissions: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: What version of node and npm are you running? You need at least node version 6.10, and npm 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm` to clear npm cache. Then try running the command with `sudo npm i @angular/cli` again